# Google Cloud SQL doesnt work when deployed to appspot

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-sql

I have a GWT project, using google sql cloud database. Everything works fine when developing locally ( development mode ). But when I deploy it to appspot it can't connect to to the database.

Doesn't anyone have an idea why this is? Should I change permissions somewhere ? I'm pretty much  lost.

I must say there is another deployed project using this database.

Thanks in advance :)

UPDATE:

```
     2012-11-02 16:14:59.888
     Uncaught exception from servlet
     java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
     com/layout/server/EntityServiceImpl :                
     Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

My App Engine log gave the following error, which is not database related. I've been using JRE 7 which appearantly is not compatible with GAE. ( appengine.google.com -> log ).

I'm trying to use JDK6 now and see what happens :)

This was the problem, changed to JDK 6 and everything is solved now. Had nothing to do with my database. Just the Java Version.

Comment: Have you checked out https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/developers-guide

Comment: Yea I have! I've read trough all the documentation. I'm starting to think you can only use the database for 1 deployed webb app.